NaN grad norm even with a stable loss and gradient
Currently I am working on a custom fine-tune of several code LLMs and while working on the DeepSeekCoder I encountered a strange behaviour.
When training the model earlier or later the loss goes to zero while the gradient_norm goes to NaN.
Usually this means that the training parameters weren't set up in a good way, however it seems that changing the parameters does not change the fact that earlier or later this still happens.
Using different gradient clippings, batch sizes and learning rates (2e-5 - 4e-6) did not help at all. In my last trial the results looked pretty good, because the losses dropped slowly and the gradient was quite stable for the entire run, but then the run ended with the same result again. Since the methods to avoid this did not work well and the statistics look stable enough to not assume some kind of overfitting or gradient explosion I am left perplexed.
Some more helpful info:
Library: Unsloth
rsLoRa rank: 128
rsLoRa alpha: 16
quantization: NF4
lr_scheduler: cosine
weight decay: 0.01
max_grad_norm: 0.3 or 1.0
Here are the last statistics:
Step, Loss, grad_norm
263 0.9913 0.160921
264 Evaluation step with loss: 1.015229
265 1.0015 0.146931
266 1.0656 0.186978
267 0.9506 0.152463
268 0.8927 NaN
267 0.0000 NaN

